# how to forward ports in Trendchip HG 520 modem?

Tags: networking, port, modem

I want to forward ports in my Trendchip HG 520 modem , I am using Windows 7 and Ubuntu Server Edition 9.10 .Please help.

Answer (score 1):

have you seen portforward.com ?